# PermissionError During loading a pytorch model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, yolo

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='yolov5-master/yolov5-master/runs/train/weights/last.pt', force_reload=True)
```

When I run this line of code in my Jupyter notebook, I get a permission error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\username/.cache\\torch\\hub\\ultralytics_yolov5_master\\requirements.txt'
```